# IONIC post request throwing error

Tags: angular, laravel, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to make an POST login api call from my ionic 3 application to my laravel api.
But when ever i try to get data it trow an error i am not very sure what could be the cause.

My code 
In provider

```
postData(credentials, type){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

      this.http.post(
          apiUrl+type,
          JSON.stringify(credentials),
          { headers: headers }
      ).subscribe(res=>{
        resolve(res.JSON());
      }),(err)=>{
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

From my login page

```
responseData:any;
  userData={"provider":"","email":"","password":""};
login() {
    //Get email address and password and validate
    this.authService.postData(this.userData,"login").then((result)=>{
      this.responseData = result;
      localStorage.setItem('userToken',JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
      //console.log(this.responseData);
      console.log(this.userData);
    },(err)=>{
      //connection failed message
    });

    // Once validated go to home page
    //this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);

  }
```

So when i am making api call i was expecting it to give me

```
{"status":200,"msg":"Successfully loged in","token":"Z82VWTdABK9hcEvnng5kGR2NWW9iX1giewX5B6fw8jUFhVpN1OjIZPKGcwq1"}
```

But instead of this i am getting this

```
POST http://localhost:8100/://localhost:8000/api/login 404 (Not Found)

ERROR Response {_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta char…//localhost:8000/api/login</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, …}headers: Headers_headers: Map(7) {"content-security-policy" => Array(1), "x-content-type-options" => Array(1), "connection" => Array(1), "x-powered-by" => Array(1), "content-length" => Array(1), …}_normalizedNames: Map(7) {"content-security-policy" => "content-security-policy", "x-content-type-options" => "x-content-type-options", "connection" => "connection", "x-powered-by" => "x-powered-by", "content-length" => "content-length", …}__proto__: Objectok: falsestatus: 404statusText: "Not Found"type: 2url: "http://localhost:8100/://localhost:8000/api/login"_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta charset="utf-8">↵<title>Error</title>↵</head>↵<body>↵<pre>Cannot POST /://localhost:8000/api/login</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵"__proto__: Bodyconstructor: ƒ Response(responseOptions)toString: ƒ ()__proto__: Object
```

I did check in the `postman` `localhost:8000/api/login` it gives success result but not when i call from my ionic app.
I am very new to ionic so not very sure what is going on can any please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not showing us how your `apiUrl` looks like, but based on the error and url you are getting:

```
POST http://localhost:8100/://localhost:8000/api/login 404 (Not Found)
```

sounds like you are trying to use relative path in url. You need to provide the complete url, otherwise Angular will apply localhost in front.

So your `apiUrl` should looke like:

```
apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/';
```

where `type` in this case would then be `login`.

Also you don't need to use `JSON.stringify` in your request :)

Comment: Hi @Alex , yes my `apiUrl`    looks like the same u mentioned it is like this `let apiUrl = "http:://localhost:8000/api/";`  and as per your suggestion i took off the `JSON.stringify` , even after that the error persist. Could it be becz my API is in another port and my ionic is running on different port? Still it should not be a problem becz i have enabled `CORS`

Comment: you have two `::` in your apiUrl, should be just one. Is it a typo here? If this were a cors issue, you would get a completely different error, there is definitely going something on with your url :)

Comment: now i m feeling like stupid for not seeing that simple mistake :P
tysm for this help,was so consumed that i overlooked small errors :P ty again :))

Comment: No problem! Happens to all of us, we get blind and just need a new set of eyes. Have a nice weekend and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try giving requestUrl like this.

```
let requestURl = apiUrl+type;
this.http.post(
          requestURl,
          JSON.stringify(credentials),
          { headers: headers }
      ).subscribe(res=>{
        resolve(res.JSON());
      }),(err)=>{
        reject(err);
      }
    });
```

because you are providing relative url, angular won't be able to pick that and it will add localhost:// before the path

Comment: same error,
Why the request url getting changed from `localhost:8000/login` to `"http://localhost:8100/://localhost:8000/api/login"` is this suppose to happen?

Comment: no, it is not supposed to happen, in some cases I have seen ionic adding origins but it does not change requestURL